# Font height differs for different font weights

Tags: html, css, fonts, webfonts

I just added a webfont to my CSS file. I'd like to use different weights of the same font.
However if I set `font-size: 14px` at least Chrome and Firefox render the font in rather strange way.

All characters with `font-weight: normal` are in fact only 13px high and the bold parts are 15px high.†

**Screenshot:** (`font-size` set to 13px, 14px and 15px):

[image: Example]
[image: Example @3x]

**CSS `font-face` declaration:**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Frutiger';
    src: url('frutiger.eot');
    src: url('frutiger.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('frutiger.woff') format('woff'),
         url('frutiger.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Frutiger';
    src: url('frutiger-bold.eot');
    src: url('frutiger-bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('frutiger-bold.woff') format('woff'),
         url('frutiger-bold.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

**Usage Example:**

```
<p style="font-family: Frutiger; font-size: 13px">ABCABC<strong>ABCDABCD</strong>ASDFASDF</p>
<p style="font-family: Frutiger; font-size: 14px">ABCABC<strong>ABCDABCD</strong>ASDFASDF</p>
<p style="font-family: Frutiger; font-size: 15px">ABCABC<strong>ABCDABCD</strong>ASDFASDF</p>
```

**Source of font:**

Unknown, file has been passed along in my company for years. I used Font Squirrel to generate the *.woff, *.svg, and *.eot files. Same results with and without Font Squirrel's hinting feature.

**Live Example:**

http://font-render-issue.herokuapp.com/

Is there a way I can fix this?

<sub>† If you blend the first line (13px) over the second (14px) you can see that the non-bold parts match exactly. If you do the same thing with the second and third (15px) line, you can see that the bold parts match (at least in terms of height).</sub>

Comment: Show us some code, and identify the source of the font. Explain why you think characters are 13px high.

Comment: Code still missing (no HTML, no CSS that actually uses the font), and you don’t specify where you got this “Frutiger” from.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Sorry, I added the missing bits. If you need more details, just contact me.

Comment: Can you provide the font file(s)? Can you try `text-rendering: geometricPrecision;`?

Comment: `text-rendering` sounds very promising, I didn't know about that. Unfortunately, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: I find this an interesting question/problem. But can't help you any further without the font files. Can you share them? Do you've got a live page?

Comment: @allcaps Thank you for you effort! I'm very glad that you take a look. I setup a little live site, you'll find the link in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Like Jukka K. Korpela says, there is no CSS that actually uses the font.
2) The strange rendering you experience is the browser that tries to fake the bold style.

CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Frutiger';
    src: url('frutiger.eot');
    src: url('frutiger.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('frutiger.woff') format('woff'),
         url('frutiger.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Frutiger';
    src: url('frutiger-bold.eot');
    src: url('frutiger-bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('frutiger-bold.woff') format('woff'),
         url('frutiger-bold.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}

/* You did this inline with style="...". */
/* The font from the first @font-face */
p { font-family: Frutiger; }
/* Gets the bold font from the second @font-face */
strong { font-weight: bold; } 

.small { font-size: 13px; }
.medium { font-size: 14px; }
.large { font-size: 15px; }
```

HTML:

```
<p class="small">ABCABC<strong>ABCDABCD</strong>ASDFASDF</p>
<p class="medium">ABCABC<strong>ABCDABCD</strong>ASDFASDF</p>
<p class="large">ABCABC<strong>ABCDABCD</strong>ASDFASDF</p>
```

**EDIT**

The font's look fine on my machine (Mac, Firefox, Safari). woff files are used.

Then I submitted the example.html to browsershots: http://browsershots.org/http://font-render-issue.herokuapp.com/example.html#
A lot of different outputs. Windows needs (better) hinting.

The Grid Fit ('gasp' table) of the fonts have one entry. They both have one range defined at 65535, which is okay.

[image: GASP]

I also bumped into the copyright info. You might want to consider alternative fonts. ;) http://joelcrawfordsmith.com/new/font/frutiger

The two fonts are from the same release. But a local file may take precedence. You can disable loading local files with the font face smiley hack.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Graublau Web';
  src: url('GraublauWeb.eot');
  src: local('☺︎'),
         url('GraublauWeb.otf') format('opentype');
}
```

This is all I can think off for now.

Comment: You _can_ declare different weights and styles under the same `font-family`, so you can just say `font-weight: bold` instead of `font-family: FrutigerBold`.

Comment: @allcaps With your solution `strong` is even bigger than before (bold font + fake browser bold). If I set `font-weight: normal` for `strong` I end up with the same rendering issue as I had before.

Comment: @RoelN: Thanks for the comment. You are right: Using the same font-family name keeps things simple and provides a fallback.

Comment: Thank you for analysis! As you pointed out, copyright is apparently a problem. Let's look if my boss is interested in actually buying the font for web usage or if might consider your proposed alternative (which would certainly be sufficient in our case and would solve my rendering problems)